# Optimise Algorithm to find Gradual Learning Curve

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, optimization

Lets say a course consists of 5 tutorials, named from A to E, and during the course the student learns 7 unique pieces of information, which I number from 1 to 7. The information learned in a given tutorial is set in stone, however I am free to teach the tutorials in any order. For example, I could teach Tut C first if I wanted to.

```
Tut A: (1,2,3,4)
Tut B: (5,6,7)
Tut C: (2,3)
Tut D: (5,6)
Tut E: (1,2,3)
```

So lets say I was to teach the tutorials in this order:

```
Ordering 1:

Tut A: (1,2,3,4)
Tut B: (5,6,7)
Tut C: (2,3)
Tut D: (5,6)
Tut E: (1,2,3)
Tut F: (1,3)
```

Then the student will learn 4 pieces of information in the first tutorial and 3 new pieces of information in the second tutorial. Leaving nothing to learn in subsequent tutorials. This is not a good way to order the tutorials since the student is expected to learn too much new information at the start of the course (a steep learning curve). The following ordering is better:

```
Ordering 2:

Tut C: (2,3)
Tut F: (1,3)
Tut E: (1,2,3) 
Tut A: (1,2,3,4)
Tut D: (5,6)
Tut B: (5,6,7)
```

Here the student learns two things in the first tutorial, 1 new thing in the second, 1 new thing in the third, nothing new in the the forth, two new things in the fifth, and 1 new thing in the last tutorial.

This ordering gives almost the same result:

```
Ordering 3:

Tut C: (2,3)
Tut E: (1,2,3)
Tut F: (1,3) 
Tut A: (1,2,3,4)
Tut D: (5,6)
Tut B: (5,6,7)
```

I have written the following function:

```
def curve(tutorials):
    covered = set()
    for t in tutorials:
        new = set(t).difference(covered)
        covered.update(new)
        yield len(new)


# Ordering 1:
print(tuple(curve(((1,2,3,4), (5,6,7), (2,3), (5,6), (1,2,3), (1,3)))))

# Ordering 2:
print(tuple(curve(((2,3), (1,3), (1,2,3,4), (1,2,3), (5,6), (5,6,7)))))

# Ordering 3:
print(tuple(curve(((2,3), (1,2,3), (1,3), (1,2,3,4), (5,6), (5,6,7)))))
```

which I call with the data for the three orderings described above. This results in the following output:

```
(4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1)
(2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1)
```

I then measure the steepness of these learning curves using the following function:

```
def steepness(r):
    return sum((r[i]*(len(r)-i) for i in range(len(r))))
```

which gives the following results for the there orderings respectfully:

```
39
26
25
```

The best solution will be that ordering with the lowest value returned for the function steepness.

So here is my entire solution for solving this problem:

```
import itertools

def curve(tutorials):
    covered = set()
    for t in tutorials:
        new = set(t).difference(covered)
        covered.update(new)
        yield len(new)

def steepness(r):
    r = tuple(r)
    return sum((r[i]*(len(r)-i) for i in range(len(r))))

tutorials = ((1,2,3,4), (5,6,7), (2,3), (5,6), (1,2,3), (1,3))
print(min(itertools.permutations(tutorials), key=lambda x: steepness(curve(x))))
```

which outputs:

```
((2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6), (5, 6, 7))
```

Now this is all well and good, but I actually have 30 tutorials which I need to order as apposed to the 5 given above and I have around 20 unique pieces of information. How might I optimise my solution so that it doesn't take forever to find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dynamic program that's exponential (base 2) in the number of topics (~ 20) and only polynomial in the number of tutorials (30).

Because of the properties of the objective function, as soon as a tutorial covers no new topics, it should be taught. Prepare a graph whose nodes are subsets of topics. There is an arc from set S1 to set S2 if there exists a tutorial T such that S2 = S1 union T. The weight of this arc is |S2 - S1| (the number of new topics) times the number of tutorials that are not subsets of S1.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import itertools


def optimize(tutorials):
    tutorials = [frozenset(tutorial) for tutorial in tutorials]
    topics = frozenset(topic for tutorial in tutorials for topic in tutorial)
    cost = {frozenset(): 0}
    predecessor = {}
    for r in range(len(topics)):
        for s1_tuple in itertools.combinations(topics, r):
            s1 = frozenset(s1_tuple)
            if s1 not in cost:
                continue
            cost1 = cost[s1]
            marginal_cost = sum(not tutorial.issubset(s1) for tutorial in tutorials)
            for tutorial in tutorials:
                s2 = s1 | tutorial
                cost2 = cost1 + len(s2 - s1) * marginal_cost
                if s2 not in cost or cost2 < cost[s2]:
                    cost[s2] = cost2
                    predecessor[s2] = s1
    order = []
    s2 = topics
    while s2 in predecessor:
        s1 = predecessor[s2]
        order.extend(tutorial for tutorial in tutorials if tutorial.issubset(s2) and not tutorial.issubset(s1))
        s2 = s1
    order.reverse()
    return order


print(optimize([{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe we can formally optimize this using some off-the-shelf mathematical programming solvers. We can track how much new stuff we learn each period and compare this against a target. Then we minimize deviations from this target. Something like:

[image]
[image]

This is a MIQP (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming) model. These solvers are readily available (e.g. via [NEOS](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/solvers/)). Instead of minimizing the sum of the quadratic deviations from the target we can also measure the absolute values of the deviations. That would make the model a Mixed Integer Programming problem (MIP) for which there are even more solvers (including open source solvers).

When I solve this using your data set I see:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem for performance is `itertools.permutations` as it has a factorial time complexity.

I suggest taking a [greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) or [hill-climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) approach.

Answer (score 0):

The place to start is that there are 30! ways to linearly arrange (order) 30 tutorials, so to get your optimal solution, you're searching over 30! possible orderings: or 265252859812191058636308480000000 solutions. Let's think about how that might be avoided --

(With super-basic algorithmic introductions, just to be safe -- sorry if I'm telling you things you know.)

I'm unlikely to come up with, or prove the optimality of, an optimal solution (before dinner anyway), but I think considering a few heuristics might be helpful. (And, until someone more algorithmic than myself comes along, you should keep in mind the possibility that you might HAVE to search all of these solutions before you find THE best one -- in which case, actually your *only* option will be to think about how to find A good solution, in a reasonable amount of time.)

The first important hint comes from your scoring function -- you have a higher penalty for presenting lots of new information early (reasonable, you don't want to scare people away early), so let's try to avoid that penalty by starting with the smallest (fewest pieces of information) tutorial first. After that, you find the tutorial that adds the fewest pieces of *new* information (breaking ties randomly) and add that one second. Continue this process until you've ordered everything -- re-run it a bunch of times because of the random aspect, and choose the solution with the lowest score.

This is a "greedy" algorithm -- you "greedily" choose the best NEXT move, without caring about how it affects the later moves. But because your later moves are less and less important, this doesn't seem like a terrible idea.

Let's compare this to your first attempt. It scales as O(n!) ("oh of en factorial") meaning with 10 tutorials, you're searching through 10! solutions, with 20, you're searching through 20!, etc -- because there are n! ways you can linearly arrange n objects.

With this new, greedy solution, first you search through all the tutorials once, to find the smallest -- then you search through the remaining tutorials, to find the one that increases the information by the least. In each step of this process (there are n steps, one each for the n tutorials you're choosing) you are performing n actions (set-diffing the existing accumulated knowledge and the tutorial under consideration). For now, let's assume performing the set-diff is one action, even though there are up to 20 elements in the sets, because set-diff is easy and 20 is 20, always a small number for a computer. We can ignore it. Now, as you continue to select elements, there will be fewer and fewer to choose *from*, making your job a little easier -- but it's easy to see that if you had to slog through 30 elements, 30 times, which is MORE than REALLY have to do, you would have performed 30^2 = 900 actions. Not 265252859812191058636308480000000.

And more generally, slogging through n objects, n times, gives you an algorithmic complexity of O(n^2) ("oh of en squared"). A *tremendous* improvement.

If you're suspicious of this solution, given that I don't promise you it works, you can always test a few cases that are small enough for you to use the exhaustive method -- meaning, test this against cases where you really do know THE optimal solution. Then you can see if the answers you get with the greedy algorithm are the same, or close.